# How comdinate int with int (1+1=11)

Tags: java

Can some one help me please? 
How combinate integers? 
When write 1+1 get 2, but I need get 11.
When write 123 + 321 need come out 123321

Comment: convert to String and concat? and parse back to an integer?

Comment: Treat integers as a String and simply concatenate them, or multiply first number accordingly to get needed number of trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `String` concatenation

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;

String combined = a+""+b;

System.out.println(combined);
```